# Is there a strategy for making Python 3.5 code with type-annotations backwards compatible?

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-3.5

I want to support new Python features in my open-source libraries. Python's new type-hinting makes it easier for users to use my software.

But it comes with a snag - it relies on a library called `typing` for some of the more interesting type annotations. That library doesn't exist in Python < 3.5.

Normally I'd handle that using a compatibility library (e.g. `six`), however there's no support for the `typing` module in `six` yet.

Another acceptable solution might be something like a `3to2` converter which can strip away the unsupported features. Unfortunately I've not yet seen a 3.5 to 3.(x<5) converter.

It seems that the only alternative available right now would be to wrap all my typedef imports into try-blocks and provide a fake typedef for the older versions of the language. That's ugly and not really the way I want to take my project.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Google doesn't turn up any such library, but there *is* a `typing` module. Is that what you're talking about? Because [there's a version of that for Python <3.5](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/typing).

Comment: sorry, you are right - are you suggesting just add it as a install-time dependency for python < 3.5

Comment: That, or you'll have to decide between not using `typing` or not supporting Python <3.5.

Comment: Well, that's the premise of the question: I want to use the new features and I want to make it support older versions. Using a backport is an acceptable solution because I can selectivly install it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Type hinting in Python 3.5 consists of two parts:

- A library of type hinting objects, called [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)
- The annotation syntax

Both can be used in earlier Python versions, or can be made to work where the annotation syntax is not yet supported.

The module has been [backported to Python 3.2 and newer](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/typing). Annotations have been supported by all Python 3 versions, right from 3.0 onwards, see [PEP 3107](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107). That means type-hinted code can work for all widely-used Python 3 distributions.

For Python 2.x, you can use [stub files](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#stub-files) instead; these are not actually executed and only the static analysis tool needs to be able to parse these. You'd still 'import' the `typing` module for these, but the module is never actually loaded, nor does it need to be installed for stub files. Stub files have the `.pyi` extension and live next to their `.py` counterparts, but include the full annotation, but no function bodies (you shoud use the `...` ellipsis literal instead).

You could look at the [Mypy stub specifications](https://github.com/python/mypy/wiki/Creating-Stubs-For-Python-Modules) for how this'll work in practice; the Python type hinting PEP was largely inspired by tools like Mypy.

Comment: https://github.com/python/mypy/wiki/Creating-Stubs-For-Python-Modules Correct link to mypy's document page.

Comment: @yegle: thanks for the heads-up, the wiki moved from the website to the github project.